# Leaflet - multicolor pattern fill

Tags: svg, leaflet, fill

I need to implement a multicolor fill in a polygon feature. The fill will be conditionally formatted according to feature properties.

Let's say that I need a polygon with a 3-color pattern like this:

```
let fillPalette = ['orange', 'green', 'blue'];
```

[image]

How is this possible in Leaflet?

In a simple `div`, this could be easily achieved with the following CSS function:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  -45deg,
  orange,
  orange 10px,
  green 10px,
  green 20px,
  blue 20px,
  blue 30px
);
```

However, Leaflet uses SVG/Canvas.

I am aware of the following plugins:

- https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern
- https://github.com/cloudybay/leaflet-polygon-fillPattern

Unfortunately, the first doesn't seem to support multi-color patterns and the second supports only images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make yourself familiar with [SVG patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#Patterns): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/svg-patterns/

Comment: @ccprog the problem is that the SVGs are created by Leaflet and, therefore, there is no straight way to define a pattern inside of the SVG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*For anyone interested, here is the solution I came up with:*

When we **create polygon**, we set `fillColor` value to point to the linear-gradient we define later.

```
let polygon = L.polygon(coords, {fillColor: 'url(#stripes)', fillOpacity: 1})
```

The **stripes** are created using **linear-gradient** without color blending, like this:

```
let fillPalette = ['orange', 'green', 'blue'];

let gradientString = `<linearGradient id="stripes" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
   <stop offset=0 stop-color=${fillPalette[0]} />
   <stop offset=33% stop-color=${fillPalette[0]} />
   <stop offset=33% stop-color=${fillPalette[1]} />
   <stop offset=66% stop-color=${fillPalette[1]} />
   <stop offset=66% stop-color=${fillPalette[2]} />
   <stop offset=100% stop-color=${fillPalette[2]} />
</linearGradient>`
```

Then we need to **define** the above linear-gradient **inside the SVG**. The SVG can be manipulated as following:

```
let svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
let svgDefs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'defs');
svgDefs.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', gradientString);
svg.appendChild(svgDefs);
```

Here is a **working fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/oyu60f1t/

Comment: Did you also manage to make it working on repeat? So that the stripes would have fixed width and you could use it for the whole complicated polygon regardless of its size.